# Haskell: How to "know" if point is inside shape?

Tags: list, haskell, replace, find, tuples

I am currently working on a h**omework** for my Haskell class and I seem to have hit a dead-end.
I have this List of Strings
`["....................",
  "....................",
  "....#####...........",
  "...##...##..........",
  "..##.....##.........",
  "..#.......#.........",
  "..#...############..",
  "..#...#...#......#..",
  "..##..#..##......#..",
  "...##.#.##.......#..",
  "....#####........#..",
  "......#..........#..",
  "......############..",
  "....................",
  "...................."]`

And I have to **replace** every '.' with '*' and ignore '.', that are inside shapes.
I currently do this:

1. Convert that List of String to a **List of tuples** in this format - (Row, Col, Char)
2. Apply **map** to this new List and create new List with succesfully replaced chars

**Map function** looks like this
  `fillTuple tupleList = map(\(row, col, char) -> if notCharInShape tupleList (row,col) && char /= '#' then (row,col,'*') else (row,col,char)) tupleList`

**notCharInShape** (for the time being) looks like this
`notCharInShape tupleList (row,col) = True`

I now struggle to find a way to "know" if given point is inside the shape. I tried googling for mathematical equations that tell if given point is inside circle, or rectangle, but I would first have to know x,y points of center and radius of the circle, which I don't.

Am I missing something, or is there really no way to tell if point is inside shape, if the shapes center, radius is unknown?

Comment: I would guess you are allowed to assume that the outer edges of the area are outside all of the shapes and proceed from there.  (It will need a more complicated algorithm than just a map.)

Comment: You are asking for a kind of flood fill algorithm. It might be wise to convert the List into a Matrix or 2D Vector or Array type first... If you google Haskell flood fill you can find a few articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your time, I've gone to sleep yesterday and right before I fell asleep I thought of solution, today I tried it and it works.
It doesn't account for two shapes having gap between them, but input will remain same, so I won't bother with that.
I created new function, that returns list of tuples (row,col) -> those points are inside some shape.
I use these points in fillTuple instead of notCharInShape function, which I deleted.

I will paste that function's code here for anyone that might encounter similar issue. `calculateNotFilledPositions _ [] = []
calculateNotFilledPositions row (xs:input) = [(row, col) | col <- [(fromMaybe (-1) (elemIndex '#' xs))..(length xs - (fromMaybe (-1) (elemIndex '#' (reverse xs)))) - 1], elem '#' xs] ++ calculateNotFilledPositions (row + 1) input`

What this function does is it basically goes over every line of input and find first index of '#' and last index of '#' and says that everything between must not be filled.
This may not be ideal, I am beginner in Haskell and functional programming in general, so if anyone wants to point out anything, feel free, I am always striving to be better :)

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function probably won't be enough because the function does not know anything about the previous values it has iterated over.

Think about how you would do this in a language like Python. You would probably have some variable that keeps track of the state of whether or not you are in a shape, then decide whether it should convert `.` to `*` or leave it as is.

I think the function `foldl` will help you. It gives you access to an initial value which you can change over time.

I'll make a slightly related example. Add one to everything in a list as long as you have not seen a zero yet or it is zero.

```hs
> snd $ foldl (\(seenZero,xs) a -> (if seenZero then True else a == 0, if seenZero || a == 0 then xs++[a] else xs++[a+1])) (False,[]) [1,2,3,4,0,1,2]
[2,3,4,5,0,1,2]
```

Here are some references.

- [Haskell Wiki - Foldr Foldl Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl')
- [Wikipedia - Fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)

Comment: @NonAlcoholicVodka Let me if the foldl example makes sense and if you need more resources to understand fold.

Comment: Thank you, foldl definitely enriched me in Haskell, but I couldn't think of a way to use it in my final solution :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in general, at least not without more information or assumptions about the shapes that are present.  If the shapes are allowed to be arbitrary, how do you know you are looking at overlapping

```
      #####      ############
     ##   ##     #          #
    ##     ##    #          #
    #       #    #          #
    #       #    #          #
    ##     ##    #          #
     ##   ##     ############
      #####
```

Rather than non-overlapping

```
      #####          ########
     ##   ##         #      #
    ##     ##       ##      #
    #   #####      ##       #
    #   #        ###        #
    ##  #        #          #
     ## #        ############
      ###
```

These two interpretations will lead to different colorings of the intersection.  But, it seems, we have no rule about which interpretation we should choose.

Does the homework specify that there will always be two shapes, one square and one circle, or something like that?

Comment: The homeworks specifies only one input, so I could technically just create a list of points that have to be inside that shape by hand, but I don't think that's the proper solution :D

Answer (score 0):

When you walk up, down, left and right from a given point and you meet a `#` on every side... the point is in a shape.

```
[ "                    ",
  "                    ",
  "    #####           ",
  "   ##   ##          ",
  "  ##     ##         ",
  "  #       #         ",
  "  #   X   #         ",
  "  #       #         ",
  "  ##     ##         ",
  "   ##   ##          ",
  "    #####           ",
  "                    ",
```

you know now the x and y coordinate of a given point and so you can check all lines before and after to check if the y is "inside" the shape. And every char before and after to check the x is "inside" the shape. If all conditions are true your point is in the shape.

```
[ "                    ",
  "                    ",
  "    #(#)#           ",
  "   ##   ##          ",
  "  ##     ##         ",
  "  #       #         ",
  " (#)  X  (#)        ",
  "  #       #         ",
  "  ##     ##         ",
  "   ##   ##          ",
  "    #(#)#           ",
  "                    ",
```

or

```
["                    ",
"                    ",
"    #####           ",
"   ##   ##          ",
"  ##     ##         ",
"  #       #         ",
"  #   #(#)########  ",
"  #  (#)X(#)     #  ",
"  ##  #  ##      #  ",
"   ## #(#)       #  ",
"    #####        #  ",
"      #          #  ",
"      ############  ",
"                    ",
"                    "]
```

Comment: Ok there are possible shapes where this solution does not work.